# Dice score changes for the same reshaped inputs

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, dice

I'm calculating the Dice score to evaluate my model for a binary image segmentation problem.

The function I wrote in PyTorch is:

```
def dice_score_reduced_over_batch(x, y, smooth=1):
    assert x.ndim == y.ndim
    # reduction over all axes except 0 i.e. batch
    axes = tuple([i for i in range(1, x.ndim)])

    intersection = torch.abs((x * y).sum(dim=axes))
    union = torch.abs(x.sum(dim=axes)) + torch.abs(y.sum(dim=axes))
    dice = torch.mean(2. * (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), dim=0)
    return dice
```

The input tensors `x` and `y` have the shape `[batch_size, nChannel, height, width]` where `nChannel=1` since ground truth is a 2d binary mask. The standard way to calculate the dice score is to compute it along the `batch` axis and taking the mean value at the end. I found that the score is affected by the way inputs are flattened.

```
+-------------------+------------------+--------+
| input tensor      | flattened tensor | dice   |
+-------------------+------------------+--------+
| [64, 1, 128, 128] | -                | 0.2754 |
+-------------------+------------------+--------+
| [64, 1, 128, 128] | [64, 16384]      | 0.2754 |
+-------------------+------------------+--------+
| [64, 1, 128, 128] | [1, 1048576]     | 0.3121 |
+-------------------+------------------+--------+
```

My best guess was this difference is due to the way values are being averaged but it's not the case. **The code must return the exact same answer irrespective of the arrangement/shape of the input data.** How this behavior can be explained? What's the best way to avoid it?

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve]? Right now we have no idea what `x` and `y` result in this error.

Comment: The calculate of the dice distance is done **between** your batch elements, precisely. So  your first dimension should always remain the same, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your dice score is averaged over the batch size:

```py
dice = torch.mean(2. * (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), dim=0)  # dim=0 means avg batch
```

So, your function computes the dice score of each element in the batch *independently* and only then averages the dice scores of all the elements in the batch.
As you can see this is not the same as computing the dice score of all the batch together.